# What's the meaning of ナーミンナイト in this song lyric?

Tags: meaning, definitions

These are the last 4 lines of the [lyrics for the song はっぴぃなんちゃら](http://www.kasi-time.com/item-33036.html)

> なごりおしいけど そろそろさよなら
>   ときめき**ナーミンナイト**
>   ときめき**ナーミンナイト**
>   ナーミンナイト(イェイ!)

What does ナーミンナイト (narmin night) mean here? Especially narmin.

Answer (score 1):

『ときめきナーミンナイト』 a [title of an episode](http://wiki.kumetan.net/index.php?%E7%95%AA%E5%A4%96%E7%B7%A8) from the web radio series Sayonara Zetsubou Housou, hosted by Shintani Ryoko and Kamiya Hiroshi.

The title is apparently a play on a phrase from the [manga かってに改蔵](http://wiki.kumetan.net/index.php?%E7%AC%AC56%E8%A9%B1%E3%80%8E%E4%B8%8D%E3%81%A3%E7%99%BA%E3%81%AE%E6%97%A5%E3%80%8F) (`ときめきウーミンナイト`) and Shintani Ryoko's character name (Hitou **Nami**).

On [another site](http://petitlyrics.com/lyrics/49783) this song is credited to 日塔奈美 (**ナーミン**).

Basically, it seems to the theme song of the web radio, and you should probably listen to some episodes to get all the references in the lyrics.

Comment: My gut feeling as a Japanese-speaker tells me there is more to it than that.  That is the play on words that I strongly feel was intended between 「なあ、みんな = "Listen, everybody!", "OK, everyone!"」 and 「ナイト = "night"」.

Comment: I've listened to [the episode](http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm20264017) and it seems to be just "Exciting night with [Namin](http://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%83%8A%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3)!".